# How to execute command after every failed command?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, logs, command

I am trying to log every time a command fails (by sending an HTTP request to my VPS) to see how many times I have messed up.

I've tried: `some_command || curl <my-vps>`. Is there a better way?

Comment: Even when for instance the `[` command fails in `[ a = b ]`?

Comment: Korn-like shells including zsh and bash have a `ERR` trap that's triggered when commands not part of conditions (and other cases like for `set -o errexit`) fail

Comment: I hope that your VPS or network link doesn't go down and every curl command fails.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a Trap for error handling.

For example:

```
trap 'echo "Error: $? occurred" >> log.txt' ERR

some_command
some_bad_command
some_command
```

Or you can use this in a script like so.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

trap 'error_handler $? $LINENO' ERR

error_handler () {
    echo "Error: $1 occurred on line $2"
}

# rest of code...
```

As a note for your use case, I would do something like this:

```
trap 'curl <my-vps> --retry 0 --silent -o /dev/null &' ERR
```

This will perform the task silently, and if this errors out it won't launch another curl.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[ "$(some-command-here)" ]] || { >&2 curl http://myvps.com; exit 1;}
```

If your command pass OK, curl will not be executed. If command fails, curl will be executed

To test this, you can do this:

```
[[ "$(ls -l)" ]] || { >&2 curl -v http://google.com; exit 1;}
```

In this case I am executing `ls -l` command which will obviouly pass OK, but curl will not be executed.

```
[[ "$(lsxx -l)" ]] || { >&2 curl -v http://google.com; exit 1;}
```

In this case, my command is broken and fails (`lsxx` does not exit) but curl will be executed.

Comment: This approach doesn’t check whether the commands succeed, it checks whether they produce any output. This means that `[[ "$(true)" ]] || echo curling` runs the `echo` command, which isn’t what’s required. The approach shown in the question *does* check whether the command succeeds: `some_command || curl …`, without any substitution or `[[` test.